# how to highlight certain environments in emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex

For example, I want to highlight the `theorem` and `lemma` environments, but leave the `proof` environment unchanged. I tried to search the variables in font locking but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not terribly easy to achieve, because AucTeX wasn't designed with that kind of extensibility in mind.  You have a couple of options:

- You can customize the `font-latex-math-environments` to add `theorem` and `lemma` to the list, and then AucTeX should highlight them as math environments.
- If you don't want them to highlight as math, you can copy/paste/modify the functions in `font-latex.el` that are responsible for recognizing math environments and tweak them for your new ones.  The relevant functions are and `font-latex-extend-region-backwards-math-envII` and `font-latex-match-math-envII`.  The former needs to be added to the list `font-latex-extend-region-functions`, so that if you edit text in the middle of a multiline region emacs can properly fix up the font locking.  The latter is added to `font-latex-keywords-2` so that emacs knows how to fontify your new regions.  The following code will do this:

```lisp
(defcustom font-latex-lemma-environments
  '("theorem" "lemma")
  "List of lemma-like environment names for font locking."
  :type '(repeat string)
  :group 'font-latex)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
(defun font-latex-match-lemma-envII (limit)
  "Match lemma patterns up to LIMIT.
Used for patterns like:
\\begin{equation}
 fontified stuff
\\end{equation}
The \\begin{equation} and \\end{equation} are not fontified here."
  (when (re-search-forward (concat "\\\\begin[ \t]*{"
                   (regexp-opt font-latex-lemma-environments t)
                   "\\*?}")
               limit t)
    (let ((beg (match-end 0)) end)
      (if (re-search-forward (concat "\\\\end[ \t]*{"
                     (regexp-quote
                      (buffer-substring-no-properties
                       (match-beginning 1)
                       (match-end 0))))
                 ;; XXX: Should this rather be done by
                 ;; extending the region to be fontified?
                 (+ limit font-latex-multiline-boundary) 'move)
          (setq end (match-beginning 0))
    (goto-char beg)
        (setq end beg))
      (font-latex-put-multiline-property-maybe beg end)
      (store-match-data (list beg end))
      t)))

(defun font-latex-extend-region-backwards-lemma-envII (beg end)
  "Return position to extend region backwards for lemma environments.
Return nil if region does not have to be extended for a multiline
environment to fit in.  The region between the positions BEG and
END marks boundaries for searching for environment ends."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char end)
    (catch 'extend
      (while (re-search-backward
          (concat "\\\\end[ \t]*{"
              (regexp-opt font-latex-lemma-environments t)
              "\\*?}") beg t)
    (when (and (re-search-backward (concat  "\\\\begin[ \t]*{"
                        (buffer-substring-no-properties
                         (match-beginning 1)
                         (match-end 0)))
                       (- beg font-latex-multiline-boundary) t)
           (< (point) beg))
      (throw 'extend (point))))
      nil)))

(add-to-list 'font-latex-keywords-2 '(font-latex-match-lemma-envII (0 'font-latex-warning-face t t)))
(add-to-list 'font-latex-extend-region-functions 'font-latex-extend-region-backwards-lemma-envII)
))
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with last version of auctex. Error is that `font-latex-extend-region-functions` does not exists anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what you mean by highlight. Do you want to change the font of the begin/end or the general face of the whole environment?

Maybe using the the [Hi Lock](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html) mode you could achieve something easily.

If this is what you are looking for, let me know and we'll figure out a simple way to add that to the AucTex hook to have it highlight every time.