# emacs does not detect \begin{comment} environment

Tags: emacs, auctex, aquamacs

In the `comment` and `verbatim` packages, there is an environment called comment, such that

```
\begin{comment}
things
\end{comment}
```

comments out `things`.

On macos, neither emacs nor aquamacs seem to default understand that it would be nice from them to use the same face for what's in there as for stuff commented out with `%`. I don't know what to do, I've tried to understand what I could make of [how to highlight certain environments in emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35605/how-to-highlight-certain-environments-in-emacs), with not much success.

Ps: I would much rather `C-c %` in the text, but I don't want to alter too much the structure of the .tex file and I suspect there should be a rather natural manner to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Aquamacs, but it should be sufficient if you install the latest version of AUCTeX (11.91), preferably from ELPA, put this line in your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

restart Emacs and open your .tex file.  `comment.el` had a bug in fontification which was [fixed upstream](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/style/comment.el?id=a90cab531b6365edf6a6ba66ad4c624b3c11d2cc).